# bash cd issue with path containing spaces: "too many arguments"

Tags: bash, quoting, cd-command

I created a path with spaces, and when I try to change directory I get "too many arguments" error message despite escaping the spaces or quoting the path :

Here are the tests I made :

```bash
# creating a path with spaces in it
$mkdir -p "01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces"

# Trying to cd
$cd 01.Silly\ Path/0.2\ With\ Plenty\ of\ /0.3\ spaces/
bash: cd: too many arguments

# Trying with sh
$sh
$ cd 01.Silly\ Path/0.2\ With\ Plenty\ of\ /0.3\ spaces/
$ pwd
/xxx/Documents/dev/01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces

# Trying to create a file using the problematic path : it works
$echo "dummy file test" > 01.Silly\ Path/0.2\ With\ Plenty\ of\ /0.3\ spaces/dummy_file.t
$cat 01.Silly\ Path/0.2\ With\ Plenty\ of\ /0.3\ spaces/dummy_file.t
dummy file test

# But command cd fails
$cd 01.Silly\ Path/0.2\ With\ Plenty\ of\ /0.3\ spaces/
bash: cd: too many arguments

$bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
lde@ldedebian ~/Documents/dev  $
$

# Tried quoting instead of escaping : still having failure with bash
$( cd "01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces/" ; pwd)
bash: cd: too many arguments

# But works fine in zsh and sh
$sh -c ' cd "01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces/" ; pwd '
/home/xxx/Documents/dev/01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces
$zsh -c ' cd "01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces/" ; pwd '
/home/xxx/Documents/dev/01.Silly Path/0.2 With Plenty of /0.3 spaces

# And the issue seems to be related to spaces indeed
$mkdir -p "01.Silly_Path/0.2_With_Plenty_of_/0.3_spaces"
$( cd 01.Silly_Path/0.2_With_Plenty_of_/0.3_spaces/; pwd)
/home/xxx/Documents/dev/01.Silly_Path/0.2_With_Plenty_of_/0.3_spaces
```

Did I miss something about Bash and spaces or is it a bug ?

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue with `cd` in Bash after creating the directory structure with the `mkdir` command that you show.  Have you overridden the built-in `cd` command with a shell function that does not properly quote the path argument? What does `type -a cd` output in your Bash shell?

Comment: Indeed there's a function cd installed by gvm. Removing that right away. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confirmed [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771869/bash-cd-issue-with-path-containing-spaces-too-many-arguments?noredirect=1#comment1473606_771869) that you had some software installed that overloaded the shell's built-in `cd` utility with its own shell function.  That shell function contains a [bug](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/457), which makes it split its pathname argument on spaces (possibly due to forgetting to double quote a variable expansion), leading to the issue you observe.

Uninstalling that software, or at least removing the shell function with

```bash
unset -f cd
```

... would likely resolve the issue.

You could also opt for correcting the issue by changing `\$*` to `\"\$@\"` and `$*` to `"$@"` [in this file](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/blob/master/scripts/env/cd).

Comment: `IFS=; set -o noglob` or switching to zsh where split+glob is not done upon unquoted parameter expansion might also help.

Comment: `type -a cd` was extremely helpful in comparison to my attempt to discover masking programs with `which cd`.